# How to access browser session cookie for K6

Tags: javascript, performance-testing, k6

I am writing some performance scripts using K6. I would like to create a user login from setup() method and use that cookie with request header of the next request within default() function. What's the easiest way to read browser cookies in K6? I had a look at cookieJar and response.cookies but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following code snippet works for this. The issue was that I previously used jar.cookiesForURL([DIRECTURL]) instead of jar.cookiesForURL(response.url)

```
let jar = http.cookieJar();
  let cookies = jar.cookiesForURL(response.url);    
  console.log("CC::"+JSON.stringify(cookies));
```